# Dereferencing PyObject in Python scripts embedded in c++ code

Tags: python, c++

I need to execute many times an embedded Python script from c++, but after few iterations the program crashes.
Here I have prepared a simple code to replicate the issue.
This is the c++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Python.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string input;
    Py_Initialize();
    PyObject* main_module = PyImport_AddModule("__main__");
    PyObject* globals = PyModule_GetDict(main_module);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << "iter " << i << endl;
        FILE* fp;
        const char* pFilename = "script.py";
        errno_t err;
        err = fopen_s(&fp, pFilename, "r");
        if (!err && fp != NULL)
        {
            PyDict_SetItemString(globals, "var", PyLong_FromLong(1));

            // run the script
            PyRun_SimpleFile(fp, pFilename);

            PyObject* output = PyDict_GetItemString(globals, "output_string");
            PyObject* str = PyUnicode_AsEncodedString(output, "utf-8", "~E~");
            cout << PyBytes_AS_STRING(str) << endl;
            Py_DECREF(output);
            Py_DECREF(str);

            fclose(fp);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Python script file is missing \n";
        }
    }

    Py_DECREF(main_module);
    Py_DECREF(globals);
    Py_Finalize();
}
```

and this is the Python script:

```
print(var)
output_string = 'executed'
```

This is the output I normally get, but it can slightly change from run to run:

> iter 0
> 1
> executed
> iter 1
> 1
> executed
> iter 2
> 1
> executed
> iter 3
> 1
> __ cached__
> iter 4
> 1
> __ cached__
> iter 5
> 1
> __ cached__
> iter 6
> C:\Users\matti\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\x64\Release\ConsoleApplication1.exe (processo 25444) terminato. Codice restituito: -1073741819.

Doing some tests, I found that removing the two `Py_DECREF(output)` and `Py_DECREF(str)` inside the loop, the program executes correctly. Maybe I misunderstood the meaning of the instruction `Py_DECREF()`, but  I am worried to have memory leaks if I remove them. Could you help correcting this code?

Comment: What does the manual for `PyDict_GetItemString` say about the reference that it returns?

Comment: @user253751 it's a borrowed reference, so I guess don't have to dereference it. In that case the same is for `mainmodule` and `globl`, so the only one I need to dereference is `str`. Is this correct?